# AngularJS Multi-level forms

Tags: angularjs

I am kind of new to AngularJS and is now facing with an issue. When I browse the solution and select an item from any category it updates the all the sections textboxes with the result instead of the on intended section.

If I have only one section then everything is perfectly fine but the moment I have more than one section, then everything goes for a toss. I know this is because of the $scope variable currentItem. I am not sure how I can solve this issue.

Any light thrown to solve the issue is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**HTML Page [`default.htm`]**

```
<html ng-app="myapp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view>
    </div>

    <script src="myapp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript [`myapp.js`]**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/home', {
    templateUrl : 'partials/Home.htm',
    controller  : 'HomeController'
  })
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
});

app.controller('HomeController', function($scope,$sce, $http, $location, $rootScope) {


    $scope.datas = [
                        {
                            "category":"First Category",
                            "items":[
                                {
                                    "itemCode":"001",
                                    "itemDescription":"Item 01"
                                },
                                {
                                    "itemCode":"002",
                                    "itemDescription":"Item 02"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "category":"Second Category",
                            "items":[
                                {
                                    "itemCode":"004",
                                    "itemDescription":"Item 04"
                                },
                                {
                                    "itemCode":"005",
                                    "itemDescription":"Item 05"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ];



    $scope.selectItem = function(parentindex, index){
        $scope.currentItem = $scope.datas[parentindex].items[index];
    }
});
```

**Partial Page [`partials/Home.htm`]**

```
<div ng-repeat='data in datas'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{data.category}} Items
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat='item in data.items' ng-click='selectItem($parent.$index, $index)'>
            <td>
                {{item.itemDescription}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Code:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input ng-model='currentItem.itemCode' type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Description:
            </td>
            <td>
                <input ng-model='currentItem.itemDescription' type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you see when you add `console.log` statements to the `selectItem` function?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what your desired functionality is, but you are using `currentItem.itemCode` and `currentItem.itemDescription` inside one of your `ng-repeat`s. That would likely cause the behavior you are seeing.